# show error message in php page when get data is null

Tags: php

I want to show error message when return value is null.

this is my form page where i submit lrno.

**index.html**

```
 <form method="post" name="myForm" action="tracking.php">
 <input type="text" name="number" id="number" placeholder="Enter LR Number" 
  required>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go">    
 </form>
```

this is my bind page where i bind data related to lrno

**tracking.php**

```
<?php

$number = $_REQUEST['number'];
$data=file_get_contents('http://apis.sd/api/Get_Loadsheet_Details/'.$number);
$datas = json_decode($data);
if($datas == "")
{
$msg = "No data avialable.";
}
?>
<input type="text" name="cmpname" value="<?php echo $datas[0]->COMPANY_NAME?>"/>
<span>
<?php if(isset($msg ))
echo $msg ;
?>
</span>
```

here when i submit the form it goes to tracking.php but error message not show if submited lrno no avialable in database but if i refresh tracking.php again it shows an error message.

Comment: print_r($datas) in both cases and post it to see the structure of the response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
if($datas == "")
{
    $msg = "No data avialable.";
}
```

to

```
if(empty($datas))
{
    $msg = "No data avialable.";
}
```

> NULL is returned if the json cannot be decoded or if the encoded data
>   is deeper than the recursion limit. So it is better to check with empty so that it can handle the above mentioned scenario.

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
if($datas == "")
```

Use

```
if (empty($var) || is_null($var))
```